# OpenShift Online home folder no write permissions

Tags: gradle, jenkins, permissions, openshift

I'm running Jenkins on OpenShift Origin, but no write permissions in home folder. This likely breaks some programs for me. Can you please help me with

1. moving home directory to location with write permissions, or
2. allowing write permissions in my home folder, or
3. telling Gradle in Jenkins to use different folder.

Answer (score 0):

The only directory writable is the OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR, this is the environment variable you can use to reference it.